# Tell varible is which one of the union type

Tags: typescript

```js
interface X {
    x: number
    z: string
}
interface Y {
    x: number
    y: number
}

type XY = X | Y
function foo(arg: XY) {
    if (arg.y) {
        console.log(arg.x + arg.y)
    }
}
```

I want to check if arg is X or Y, the most intuitive way seems like to check if there is y in arg, however TSC doesn't allow this.

What's the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`in` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) will work best in this case:

```
interface X {
    x: number
    z: string
}
interface Y {
    x: number
    y: number
}

type XY = X | Y
function foo(arg: XY) {
    if ('y' in arg) {
        console.log(arg.x + arg.y)
    }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4Chm+QDwC5kQBXAWwCNoc8AvYgZzClAHMsBfLUSWRFAE1MtXERIVqUUcgCexMlRrcsYWQAcUqYQF40yAD7JBWGKRAIwwAPYhkMa9YAUcKG2LaAlCLzJgMZCcAclkgvztXNm9sX18EW0ZrABsIADok6zYXN1T8ZABqZEjU2U8Zbk4gA)

Comment: don't know `in` can work like this, I thought it was some outdated feature

Comment: @Austaras it's been around for a while, but it works well in this case